# JFreechart preserving exact zoom position when updating chart

Tags: java, swing, zooming, jfreechart

What I want to do is preserve the exact zooming position of a JFreechart by storing 'some' variables and then resetting the zoom position on the new chart.

I have tried doing the following:

### Attempt 1

```
double zoomX = chartpanel.getScaleX();
double zoomY = chartpanel.getScaleY();

//After changing the chart
chartPanel.zoomInBoth(zoomX, zoomY);
```

But what happens is that the new chart gets zoomed in *to the center of the graph*.

Hence not to the exact zoom/drag state I had before.

### Attempt 2

What I tried next was saving the visable `lower` and `upper`bounds of the domain and range and setting these for the new chart:

```
//At top of class
private double domainMin;
private double domainMax;
private double rangeMin;
private double rangeMax;

//In main method
if (resetZoom)
{
   domainAxis.setRange(domainMin, domainMax);
   mainPlot.setDomainAxis(domainAxis);
   rangeAxis.setRange(rangeMin, rangeMax);
   mainPlot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);
}

if (!(resetZoom))
{
   domainMin = mainPlot.getDomainAxis().getRange().getLowerBound();
   domainMax = mainPlot.getDomainAxis().getRange().getUpperBound();
   System.out.println(domainMin + "," + domainMax);

   rangeMin = mainPlot.getRangeAxis().getRange().getLowerBound();
   rangeMax = mainPlot.getRangeAxis().getRange().getUpperBound();
   System.out.println(rangeMin + "," + rangeMax);
}
```

But this kept on giving the same values:

```
1.3685904E12,1.3776192E12
382.6265,519.9835

1.36846512E12,1.38025008E12
382.6265,519.9835

1.3685904E12,1.3776192E12
382.6265,519.9835

1.36846512E12,1.38025008E12
382.6265,519.9835
```

Hence I suspect the methods `.getDomainAxis().getRange().getLowerBound();` and `.getDomainAxis().getRange().getUpperBound();` do not give the `UpperBound` of the visable `axis` but of the original (full) axis.

### Attempt 3

I then came up with the idea of using `findRangeBounds(XYDataset)` which should only give the bounds of the visable data. Unfortunately, I then found [the following](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=115080) about `findRangeBounds(XYDataset)` : It doesn't work (still?) for `CandlestickRenderer` (for `XYLineAndShapeRenderer` it works fine).

So my question is: **Is there a way to accomplish what I want?**

Comment: Does `setDataBoundsIncludesVisibleSeriesOnly(true)` work?

Comment: @trashgod: I didn't know that existed! I will try it